# Профилировка с вложенными уровнями - как организовать расчет данных

Tags: java

Для ручной профилировки кода пишу код, и если для одноуровневой вложенности реализовал, но если сессии измерения времени имеют многоуровневую вложенность, то как обработать данные рассчитать результаты не могу понять. Вложенности могут иметь такой вид:

```
enterSession(“1”);
…

for(;;) {
     enterSession(“2”);

        enterSession(“3”);

                 …
        exitSession(“3”);       
     …
     exitSession(“2”);

}

     enterSession(“4”);     

     …
     exitSession(“4”);
...
exitSession(“1”);
```

Соответственно надо рассчитать "чистое" время каждой сессии. Если сессия 1 длилась 700 мс, а вложенная сессия 2 450 мс, то "чистое" время 1 сессии 250 мс.

Одноуровневую статистику сделал на TreeMap, где ключ - имя сессии, а значением временные данные. Но никак не могу понять как отслеживать, что у сессии 1 есть вложенная сессия 2, у сессии 2 есть вложенная сессия 3. А после закрытия сессии 2 может быть вложенная сессия 4, у которой нет вложенных сессий. При этом сессии могут повторяться энное количество раз.

Как это можно реализовать? Прошу не код, а идеи.
Спасибо.

Comment: А как вы ищите сессию? По уникальному имени?

Comment: Да, имя сессии уникально, но можно создать и ID для каждой сессии.

Comment: Тогда подходит. Имя сессии будет ключом.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение исходит из посылки, что вы используете идентификатор сессии для доступа к ней. Вам нужно попробовать использовать ссылочную структуру данных. Идея такова - каждая сессия знает своего родителя, но родитель не знает о ней. Для быстрого поиска по объекту будем использовать, пожалуй, структуру данных `HashMap`.
Класс `Session` должен содержать следующие переменные: `long time`, `Session parent`. Также для реализации задуманного нам там нужен следующий метод:

```
public int getTime(){
    return time - ((parent == null) ? 0 : parent.getTime());
}
```

Как происходит создание объекта сессии:
1) передаете родительскую сессию, если данная сессия вложенная
2) передаете то, по чему вы будете идентифицировать вашу сессию
3) передаете время сессии
Этот объект добавляете в `HashMap<IDType, Session>`. Когда он понадобится - берите его с помощью ключа - идентификатора сессии.